# Flex 3: progress bar with round edges

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar, flex3, rounding

Based on Flex 3, how can I skin my progress bar to make it look like [this example](http://static.micheljansen.org/uploads/progressbar-70pct-straight.png), with round corners/edges?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This example may help: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/03/27/setting-the-bar-skin-on-a-progressbar-control-in-flex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom skins for the progress bar and set the css styles to refer to your custom programatic skins.  You will need programatic skins for:


barSkin
maskSkin
trackSkin

All of these are found as styles for the ProgressBar component.


You can refer to the default skins to see how they are done:


barSkin="ProgressBarSkin"
maskSkin="ProgressMaskSkin"
trackSkin="ProgressTrackSkin"